# error in parsing json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
  [
    {
      "Id": 1234,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Message": "hiii",
      "Image": "5_201309091104109.jpg",
      "Likes": 7,
      "Status": 1,
      "OtherId": 3,
      "Friends": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Id": 201309091100159,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Message": "heyyyyyyyy",
      "Image": "",
      "Likes": 2,
      "Status": 1,
      "OtherId": 3,
      "Friends": 3
    }
  ]
]
```

I am trying to parse this JSON data in javascript,but its giving an error 
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"
Tell me how to parse or access this json data and how to get numbers of records saved in JSON data.

I am running this on firefox ..Please help me to resolve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: The JSON is valid (even though the structure is a bit odd). Maybe you are trying to parse something that is not JSON. Please post your code.

Comment: This is not JSON. ITs just object literal. Post your JSON which is string.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: This is JSON. Of course in JavaScript (or Python, Java, <insert language here>) JSON can only exist in a string, but JSON is a language independent data format. You can only talk about object literals in JavaScript source code, but the "code" posted here is not JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, But here we need to know the original string. Because of the syntax error on JSON.parse.

Comment: also i love the way of building arrays - separate array with single item, for each item. I'd like to call this data structure pattern as "Array Singleton" lol

Comment: One chance is there may be unicode character some where in your object like here : `{‌}` you are not seeing it which is inside curly braces. Paste it to notepad and use `backspace` you will find three chars there.

Comment: @FelixKling This JSON was returned by using res.send(rows) method in node.js and rows are the records selected from database. And i m receiving this JSON from a ajax function or may be i can access data like msg[0][0].Id where msg is response returned to ajax function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your msg variable is already a Javascript object literal you can access properties in it directly like you said : msg[0][0].Id

If it is a string you can use JSON.parse() function to obtain a JS object:
[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nilgundag/EdWKv/1/

```
var msg1 = [
  [
    {
      "Id": 1234,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Message": "hiii",
      "Image": "5_201309091104109.jpg",
      "Likes": 7,
      "Status": 1,
      "OtherId": 3,
      "Friends": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Id": 201309091100159,
      "PersonId": 1,
      "Message": "heyyyyyyyy",
      "Image": "",
      "Likes": 2,
      "Status": 1,
      "OtherId": 3,
      "Friends": 3
    }
  ]
];
$("#first").text(msg1[0][0].Id);

var myJSONString = '[[{"Id": 1234,"PersonId": 1,"Message": "hiii","Image": "5_201309091104109.jpg","Likes": 7,  "Status": 1,     "OtherId": 3,      "Friends": 0    }  ],  [    {      "Id": 201309091100159,      "PersonId": 1,      "Message": "heyyyyyyyy",      "Image": "",      "Likes": 2,      "Status": 1,      "OtherId": 3,      "Friends": 3    }  ]]';
var msg2 = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
$("#second").text(msg2[0][0].Id);
```

Comment: Thankss for ur answer,, now its working. I am just counting length of numbers of records returned in JSON ,using count=msg.length; and accessing all element in loop for(var i=0;i<count;i++){ msg[i][0]['Id']; }

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the json str is valid。but when that string isn't in JS enviroment..that's format is invalid.

Comment: It's valid JSON, it doesn't matter in which environment it is.